# Using css scroll snapping, how to make the image not in view blurry (less opaque)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slides {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.section-1{
background-color: blue;
}
.section-2{
background-color: yellow;
}
.section-3{
background-color: green;
}
.section-4{
background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<main class="slides">
  <section class="section-1">
    <h2>Scroll right to see it in action</h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-2">
    <h3>this and that</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="section-3">
    <h2>help</h2>
  </section>
  <section class="section-4">
    <h3>please</h3>
  </section>
</main>
```

I am making a horizontal scrollable carousel. In this div there are images, and I am using css scroll snapping where scroll-snap-align: start. The image that is up next in the list (the one that is not visible on the right) needs to be less opaque than the one that is currently in view.

[This is the look I am going for (picture of the carousel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ8wu.png)

Also while I'm here is there a chance anyone could help with endless scroll, so the images just start from the beginning again?

Comment: I didn't check if there were any discussions about it, but I guess a selector to know which element is the current "snap area" would fall into [Selectors that Depend on the layout](https://wiki.csswg.org/faq#selectors-that-depend-on-layout) pitfall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use an event listener on the scrolling container. Depending on the leftscroll value of the scroll container we either set the opacity style of an image container (which wraps the images that are placed inside the scroll container) to a lower value (blurred) or back to 1(visible).

The use of refs in React makes things a lot easier both in terms of the scroll container and the image containers.